# How to reference a file outside of model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm adding the carrierwave gem to an app in Rails, and I'm getting a weird NameError. I've followed all other posts on it, yet none of them worked. Here's the error:

```
uninitialized constant Post::ImageUploader

Extracted source (around line #2):
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

And post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Also, here's one [site](http://ruby.about.com/od/faqs/qt/Nameerror-Uninitialized-Constant-Object-Something.htm) that I went to, but it didn't describe where to place the code, so I got really confused.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: do you have `ImageUploader` class defined anywhere in your project, if not that's your problem

Comment: It's defined in /uploaders/image_uploader.rb @bjhaid

Comment: is `Uploaders` a module/class, if so, `ImageUploader` should be nested under the module, and you can do `Uploaders::ImageUploader` in your `Post` model, rails also does some magic with looking up classes based on directory structure, so you would either have to create a module `Uploaders` or just put `autoload :ImageUploader` in an initializer

Comment: Uploaders is just the folder that image_uploader.rb is located in. @bjhaid

Comment: see update to my comment

Comment: Try adding `require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'` to `config/environment.rb` file.

Comment: If I create a module called Uploaders, where would I put it? @bjhaid

Comment: It didn't work @Pavan

Comment: wrap the `ImageUploader ` class in an `Uploaders` module

Comment: I made a file called uploaders.rb, put it inside the main models folder, and put in the following: `module Uploader class ImageUploader end end` (I condensed it to save space, it's on multiple rows in the file. I added Uploaders::ImageUploader to post.rb, but now I'm getting `undefined method 'mount_uploaders' error` @bjhaid

Comment: Follow the example here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: That's exactly the tutorial that I'm following :) @bjhaid

Comment: Please show your `image_uploader.rb` file

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jake R's comments I agree. The most likely culprit is that your ImageUploader looks like this:

```
# uploaders/image_uploader.rb
class ImageUploader
  # Something here..
end
```

But should look like this:

```
# uploaders/image_uploader
module Uploaders
  class ImageUploader
    # Stuff goes here..
  end
end
```